# concat and drop duplicates from two Dataset and write a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 datasets:

df1:
Col1  : (xyz, abc) 
Col2  : (123,456)

df2:
Col1  : (xyz, abc, def)
Col2  : (567, 456, 123)

I want to see the [rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft41Z.jpg) which has differences from both the dataframes and an additional column to see from which dataframe this record came:

Below is a link of what I want. Can someone help plz

New finding:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcNEv.jpg)

This new link shows for an additional column with null, the result is showing me only df1 for all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo ucan do like this

```
new_df = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
a = new_df['Col1']+new_df['Col2'].astype(str)
b = df1['Col1']+df1['Col2'].astype(str)
new_df['from_df'] = np.where(a.isin(b), 'df1','df2')
new_df
```

**output**

```
   Col1     Col2    from_df
0   xyz     123     df1
0   xyz     567     df2
2   def     123     df2
```

[image]

Comment: The answer worked but if any of these columns has a Null it does not work. The From_df is returned with df1 only. Do I need to do a fillna?

Comment: Question is not clear. Update your question to include this scenario also.

Comment: So say if there is one more Column in both the Dataframe - Col3 and this column has NULLs in both the datasets, my result gives an output :

Comment: Col1     Col2   Col3 from_df
0   xyz     123               df1
0   xyz     567               df1
2   def     123               df1

Comment: Still not clear for me. You can edit your original question at the top itself (formatting here in the comments is difficult)

Comment: please check the new link provided..It shows me DF1 for all the rows with your query

Comment: it is working correctly for me even with another column which has null values. added a picture also. check.

Comment: I am trying with 7 fields out of these 2 are null and it returns DF1 for all the records. Can you please try with 7 fields and 2 fields with NULL. Is it because of some indexing that it changes the result.